# SODIMM timings vs DIMM timigs

Tags: latency, sodimm

I try to google it but there is no information about why timings of DIMM DDR4 3200MHz is better (lower) than timings of SODIMM DDR4 3200MHz ?

I just found that fact on marketplaces, but there is no explanation.
Usually values are CL16-18 DIMM and CL20-22 for SO-DIMM.

Thank you!

p.s. I believe that is relates to thing we discussing here, and guys of course you ve already known an answer and can share with me.